# Using Guava's ComparisonChain to compare strings containing roman numbers

Tags: java, comparison, guava, comparisonchain

I have class implementing `Comparator<String>` which should sort strings in such manner that strings with first word being roman number should be before string that don't begin with roman number, and if both strings begin with roman literal, there should be two cases:

1. sort by roman number and then if equal by rest of string
2. sort by rest of string and if equal than roman number

I wanted to use Guava's [ComparisonChain](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) but encountered two problems:

1. During debug in Eclipse I can't see what's inside ComparisonChain object (even while being in ComparisonChain class).
2. `comparisonChain.result()` in second example above always returns 0 (I can't inspect flow because of problem #1) for values like "XI Something", "III Something" etc. (conversion to long is OK - I checked values).

What is the problem here? I can use `comparisonChain` object like above (by making variable and adding `.compare`s in some ifs like with builders), can't I?

This code:

```
  if (romanComparisionFirst) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
        .compare(Roman.toLong(leftFirstWord), Roman.toLong(rightFirstWord))
        .compare(WORDS_JOINER.join(leftWordsTail), WORDS_JOINER.join(rightWordsTail), collator)
        .result();
  } else {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
        .compare(WORDS_JOINER.join(leftWordsTail), WORDS_JOINER.join(rightWordsTail), collator)
        .compare(Roman.toLong(leftFirstWord), Roman.toLong(rightFirstWord))
        .result();
  }
```

and this:

```
  final ComparisonChain comparisionChain = ComparisonChain.start();
  if (romanComparisionFirst) {
    comparisionChain
        .compare(Roman.toLong(leftFirstWord), Roman.toLong(rightFirstWord))
        .compare(WORDS_JOINER.join(leftWordsTail), WORDS_JOINER.join(rightWordsTail), collator);
  } else {
    comparisionChain
        .compare(WORDS_JOINER.join(leftWordsTail), WORDS_JOINER.join(rightWordsTail), collator)
        .compare(Roman.toLong(leftFirstWord), Roman.toLong(rightFirstWord));
  }
  return comparisionChain.result();
```

give different results - first case is OK, second always 0. So question is: **Can I use `ComparisonChain` like shown if second case or is this behavior a bug?**

Comment: Not really an answer (JB is totally right), but can I suggest having two separate orderings--a roman one for the words, and another one for the tails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each `compare` method of the `ComparisonChain` returns a `ComparisonChain`, which is not necessarily the chain on which compare is invoked. The first snippet doesn't ignore the result (and is thus correct), but the second one ignores the result, and is thus incorrect.

It would be correct if it did:

```
comparisionChain = comparisionChain.compare(...).compare(...);
```

See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html#line.89 for the source code.

Comment: So basically `ComparisonChain` can't be used as `Immutable*.Buider`? I mean `final Builder<String> builder = ImmutableSet.builder();` and then `if (condition) { builder.add(element);`? Why is that?

Comment: (Can't edit above comment) Why result isn't computed later when `comparisonChain.result()` is invoked? I mean the concept, I can see the code explaining my mistake :)

Comment: Well, that's how Guava decided to implement the comparison chain. It makes things a bit simpler to just ignore any subsequent compare once a previous one has already found the result.

Comment: I'll deal with it (maybe I'll ask on guava-discuss), nonetheless you answered my question (`comparisionChain = comparisionChain.compare(...).compare(...);` did help), thanks!